# Retrieve the image path of the file uploaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

I have written a code that will allow the user to upload an image to the server. My code is as follows:

My backend is in `Node JS`. What I want is to retrieve the file path of the image file so i can upload it. This is to be done from the `Node JS` side.

The code I have written doesn't work. It crashes while retrieving the path of the image file.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="input-700" name="kartik-input-700[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading" name="fileupload">

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#input-700").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "/filllll/uploadIm", // server upload action
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
    uploadAsync: true,
    maxFileCount: 1
});
var fullPath = $("#input-700").val();
alert(fullPath);

    });
</script>
```

Node JS

```
router.post('/uploadIm', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('IThe path of the file' + res.fieldname);

});
```

Comment: You can use a npm module like "multer" to handle file upload. It makes file uploading very easier by adding a file field in req.

Answer (score 0):

Express does not this out of the box. You need to handle `multipart/form-data`. The easiest way to do this - to use the middleware. For example, [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer):

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: Can you also show me the corresponding HTML and JQuery function as well. I am a newbie. :S

Comment: Quite a lot of tutorials on the internet on this topic :) For example: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/ajax-file-upload-node-js/